# Searchable list of objects in Java

Tags: java, list, search

I want to create a large (~300,000 entries) List of self defined objects of the class `Drug`.
Every Drug has an ID and I want to be able to search the Drugs in logarithmic time via that ID.
What kind of List do I have to use?
How do I declare that it should be searchable via the ID?

Comment: What is the range of the IDs?

Comment: Any chance to put them in a DB and let it do the work with help of SQL/JDBC? This is undoubtely going to be more fast and efficient.

Comment: @BalusC only if the data is not changing too much. If he has to update everything in short intervals and persistence is not needed, then a DB won't make much sense. But my first thoughts are pointing towards a DB too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various implementations of the Map interface should do what you want.

Just remember to override the hashCode() method of your Drug class if you plan to use a HashMap.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but remind me why hashCode() must be overridden? Isn't the default one pretty good?

Comment: You only need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` only if you want to use your class as the **key** of a `Map` or if you want to put it in a `Set`. If you simply want to use it as the value of a `Map` then you don't need to implement them. Also: **If** you implement `equals()`, then you **must** implement `hashCode()` as well.

Comment: Having fine grained control over the hashcode you can guarantee that map entries are evenly distributed among buckets. The worst case scenario is when all entries land in the same bucket and the complexity of lookup becomes O(n).

Comment: The default implementation just takes the address in memory to be the hash code. If you use your Drug object as a key, you could not do the following:

myMap.put(new Drug("Whatever"), 23.42);
myMap.get(new Drug("Whatever"));

because both Drug instance have a different hashCode and the latter will return null. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() for details.

Comment: Assuming that the type of an ID is String, and that that is the key, there is no need (and no way) to override the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: RE Malax: But bear in mind that this only applies if you are using your Object as the key, as Joachim notes. But normally the key is not the target object itself, but some identifier. In this case Christian says he has a "drug id". If this can be stored in a String or an Integer, as seems likely, then those classes already have generally good hashCode functions.

Comment: @Malax: the default implementation does *not* just take the address in memory. It takes the identityHashCode (as defined by `System.identityHashCode()`) which *may* be based on the position in memory. Think of a 64bit JVM: how could a 32bit value **be** the position in memory in that case?

Comment: @Joachim, you are absolutely right, I omitted the whole identityHashCode part in my comment to keep it simple. But you are right. :-)

@Jay: "If you use your Drug object as a key" is exactly what i wrote  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Drug implements Comparable<Drug> {

    public int compareTo(Drug o) {
         return this.id.compareTo(o.getId());
    }
}
```

Then in your List you can use binarySearch

```
    List<Drug> drugList; <--- List of all drugs
    Drug drugToSearchFor; <---- The drug that you want to search for, containing the id
    // Sort before search
    Collections.sort(drugList);
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(drugList, drugToSearchFor);

    if (index >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you use TreeMap instead of List using the ID as your Key?

Comment: FYI, the reason I suggested TreeMap is because TreeMap is guaranteed to run contains, get and put in O(log n)

Comment: if you don't need to have the keys ordered, then this is unnecessary

Comment: The requirement was for logarithmic search, so I think it must be.

Comment: The advantage of TreeMap is that you can retrieve the items in order by key. This was not stated as a requirement in the original question, though of course that doesn't prove it isn't a requirement. But the requirement for a logarithmic search is met by a HashMap. You don't need a TreeMap if that's the only issue.

Comment: Since the user originally suggested List, it would seem order is required.  But true, it was not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2):

If searching by a key is important for you, then you probably need to use a Map and not a List. From the [Java Collections Trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html):

> The three general-purpose Map 
>   implementations are HashMap, TreeMap 
>   and LinkedHashMap. If you need
>   SortedMap operations or key-ordered
>   Collection-view iteration, use
>   TreeMap; if you want maximum speed and
>   don't care about iteration order, use
>   HashMap; if you want near-HashMap
>   performance and insertion-order
>   iteration, use LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the high number of entries you might consider to use a database instead of holding everything in memory.

If you still want to keep it in memory you might have a look at b-trees.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any list, and as long as it is sorted you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).
But I would use a Map which searches in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I know I am pretty redundant with this statement, but as everybody said isnt this exactly the case for a Map ?